# JavaScript (ES6) const with curly braces

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

I'm new to ECMAScript 6, and while trying to learn Ember, I've seen the following code style occasionally:

```
const {
  abc,
  def
} = Object;
```

I've searched Google and many sites explaining the new ES6 specifications. I know this is not the current implementation, because my console gives an error when I input that.

What does this code mean?

I pasted this snippet into [Babel's transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/), and this is what it returned:

```
"use strict";

var abc = Object.abc;
var def = Object.def;
```

I'm still confused as to what this is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Here's an example, pretty good site when wanting to play with some ES6 stuff. http://www.es6fiddle.net/ih5zgb2r/

Comment: ugh. how is `const {someKey} = someObj` a better alternative to `const someKey = someObj.someKey`

Comment: @ZachSmith, it's a good alternative when you have multiple of them, such as `const {name, version, type} = app;` example in the accepted answer below.

Comment: @jaywalker - yes. I pretty much use it constantly now

Comment: personnel = {
  age: 45,
  sex: f,
  salary:2000
 ...
}
const {salary, age, sex} = personnel
same as 
const salary = personnel.salary
const sex = personnel.sex
const age = personnel.age

Answer (score 313, accepted):

It's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Specifically, an [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) assignment.

It might help to see it rewritten in a more verbose way.

```
const abc = Object.abc;
const def = Object.def;
```

It's a shorthand way to initialise variables from object properties.

```
const name = app.name;
const version = app.version;
const type = app.type;

// Can be rewritten as:
const { name, version, type } = app;
```

You can do the same kind of thing with arrays, too.

```
const a = items[0];
const b = items[1];
const c = items[2];

// Can be written as:
const [a, b, c] = items;
```

Comment: i think your link is incorrect, hmm digest cycle.

Comment: You might want to add a link to MDN in your answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: For anyone who also writes PHP, this is kind of the equivalent of the [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) construct.