# What does "const { PI } = Math" mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are these constructions the same?

```
const {PI} = Math;
```

and

```
const PI = Math.PI;
```

What are benefits of using the first example?

Comment: The first is just a shorthand syntax for the second (ES6). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: it lóòks more cool ...

Comment: *"Are these constructions the same?"* They have the same result: A constant called `PI` with the value from `Math.PI`. *"What are benefits of using the first example?"* You avoid having to repeat the identifier `PI`. In the general case, if you are picking more than one thing (`const {a, b, c} = obj;`), you avoid repeating `obj.` *and* the identifier names. In general, avoiding repetition is good because it removes an opportunity for error (e.g., changing one of them and not the other, mistyping one, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces around the variable name is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment),

and `const {PI} = Math;` will translate to `const PI = Math.PI`

Answer (score -1):

It is a so-called "destructuring assignment".

Searching this site I found a similar question with a good answer:
[Javascript (ES6) const with curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798717/javascript-es6-const-with-curly-braces)

Comment: *"Searching this site I found a similar question with a good answer:"* Then comment saying you've found a duplicate (and when you have enough rep, close vote), don't post an *answer*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder take it easy and let people get some reputation  :D

Comment: @AmaniBenAzzouz: I am taking it easy. SO will turn into a morass of useless duplication, like every attempt at solving this problem before it, if people constantly post duplicate answers. *(Not my dv, btw, ar34z)*

Comment: Oops, you're right @T.J. Crowder. My bad. It's been a while since my last activity here... All the answers here have been downvoted without any comment (as you haven't done mine). That doesn't help any of them at all either. I'll vote for this one though.