# Using const with curly brackets

Tags: javascript

I came across the following code:

```
const { userinfo } = userInfo;
```

I'm wondering, why do we use curly brackets with the const here?

Comment: Then there is also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798717/javascript-es6-const-with-curly-braces

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript this syntax is called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and more specifically [object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring). Let's say you have an object:

```
const obj = { data: {...}, user: {...} }
```

For instance, when you write:

```
const { data, user } = obj
console.log(data)
```

Here you define new variables `data` and `user` and assign corresponding property values from the object `obj` to those variables.

---

It seems like in your case you have a local variable:

```
userInfo = {userInfo: {...} }
const { userinfo } = userInfo;
```

Deconstructing `userInfo` into `{ userInfo }` would give you an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'userInfo' has already been declared